# use postman to pass argument to flask always returns None

Tags: python, flask, postman

i want to use postman to pass parameters. however after i send POST request in postman, it always returns **None** for **each** parameter that i want to get . What did I do wrong?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def Todo_all():

    ......

    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.values.get("title", type=str, default=None)
        description = request.values.get("description", type=str, default=None)
        return mytodo.create(title, description)
```

I have also tried

```
request.form.get
request.data
```

and I've tried print the value in console, and I get **None** as well

```
print request.form.get('title')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Postman, make sure you're submitting the POST request with the content type of "x-www-form-urlencoded"

[image: postman example]